# SSRS Excel export set custom Metadata - author

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that is working fine except when a user exports to excel and saves the file down the metadata for "Author" (what I would call CreatedBy"), "Last Modified By", "Created" (date) and "Last Modified" (date) are all empty.

Is there a way to set these during export?
Users require these fields to not be empty and at present have to open the exported file and resave it.

I have looked into the the rsreportserver.config file and cannot see anywhere to set these.
I have also tried to set the "Author" & "Description" fields in the Properties window of the report in Visual studio but this appears to be the author of the report and doesn't flow through the export renderer and the excel file "author" remains blank.
According to the Microsoft Docs the excel renderer has a Document Property (Report Element properties) called "Author" but I cannot find anywhere to set this.

Ideally I would like to set this to be the windows AD name of the person who executes the export but at this stage (having wasted the best part of a full day scouring the internet and reading blogs and docs) I would accept even being able to hard code this with a generic piece of text - e.g. "SSRS_Export"

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: There is an Author property in the Report's properties but this apparently is not used in the Excel renderer (I just tried it). Oddly, it does work when exporting to Word, the Author is written to the document properties. Short of writing your own extension I'm not sure that you will be able to do this directly from SSRS. You could write a simple Excel macro that did this I suppose, that iterates thru all files in a folder and sets the properties, not nice but might save you a little time. (GGMU!)

Comment: Thanks, yes I already tried setting that Author property, and excel macro isn't viable as the exports won't always be saved into same folder by end users. Very frustrating

Comment: I assume having their name just in the Workbook somewhere will not suffice..?

Comment: You could contact Aspose and see if their renderer supports this. It's not listed in the features but worth a try I guess. https://products.aspose.com/cells/reporting-services

Comment: Microsoft *claims* that the Excel renderer does use the Report Author as the Excel Author. Obviously this is not correct and this functionality does not work. Unfortunately, it will probably never be fixed. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Name in workbook not an option, end users trying to import the file into another 3rd party process that is rejecting out due to the lack of author, they have to review the file first anyway, so just told them to click save after their review which will add the author. Just seems like a fairly big flaw in the Microsoft excel renderer. Thanks